# Wrong order of reactions DiscordBot

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I want it to react to a certain user with a specific emotes but those emotes are not in the order they should be and bot adds them randomly, how can I solve it?

**Code:**

```
client.on('message', (msg) => {
    if(msg.author.id  === "424253410918006810" ) { 
        msg.react('')  
        msg.react('')
        msg.react('')
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making your on message function asynchronous.
Like this:

```js
client.on('message', async (msg) => {
    if(msg.author.id  === "424253410918006810" ) { 
        await msg.react(''); 
        await msg.react('');
        await msg.react('');
    }
});
```

msg.react returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and promises aren't always fulfilled in the order you start them in. You can, however, use await to wait for the promise to resolve before continuing.